# How to display different custom users after logging in Django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 custom users, student and teacher. I want that if student is logged in, a particular message is displayed, otherwise if teacher is logged in, another message to show.

```css
 {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            {% if user is student %}
                <p>Welcome, {{ user.student.surname }} Thanks for logging in.</p>
                {% else %}
                {% if user is teacher%}
                <p>Welcome, {{ user.teacher.surname }} Thanks for logging in.</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
```

```html
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)


User.student = property(lambda p: Student.objects.get_or_create(user=p)[0])
User.teacher = property(lambda p: Teacher.objects.get_or_create(user=p)[0])
```

Comment: I think you can simply do `{% if user.student %}` or `{% if user.teacher %} `

Comment: @LaurynasTamulevičius that won't work because those properties will try to create the student or teacher object regardless.

Comment: I guess in that case you need some hacky way around this. You could pre-check currently logged in user type in the views and pass it to the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I believe it's not a really good idea to have `user.teacher` and `user.student` as a property for two reasons:
1. I assume that a user can be either a student or a teacher, but not both (please correct me if I'm mistaken). You are using `get_or_create`, so, for instance, if you'll try to access a user `teacher` property with user being already a student, you will end up in the situation when the user is both a student and a teacher.
2. Django ORM already does this for you: using [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) you can reference `Teacher` or `Student` object from your `User` object as `user.teacher` or `user.student` as long as the corresponding User or Teacher exists.

You can use `hasattr` to check if the given user is a teacher or a student:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
     @property
     def is_teacher(self):
          return hasattr(self, 'teacher')
     @property
     def is_student(self):
          return hasattr(self, 'student')
```

Then render your template accordingly:

```
{% if user.is_teacher %}
    # Do teacher-related logic
{% elif user.is_student %}
    # Do student-related logic
{% else %}
    # This should not be the case, but you may want to display an error message or something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, but I get an error like: Could not parse the remainder: '(user,' from 'hasattr(user,'

Comment: @DannM could you please share the code and the full traceback? Wild guess: you may have lost a quote somewhere

Comment: @DannM my bad, I was not very familiar with django template system, so I assumed you can use an arbitrary built-in function in them. Turns out you can't, so I suggest you extract the logic of defining user's type to a model method or property, as I pointed in the answer